# Where do I define the return type from and AWS API gateway call, so that the auto-generated SDK includes a class modeling the returned value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API gateway. I can see from using the sample AWS API Gateway that the auto generated SDK has a return type of pet, as defined in Pet.java.

When I auto generate and SDK from another AWS API Gateway a class called Empty.java is auto-generated in place of this Pet class.

I have looked at the sample API Gateway but I can not see where the value that defines the Pet class is configured. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. This is defined under the models section for the particular API Gateway.